# No of Minimum spanning trees should be 2 but solution says 1

Tags: minimum-spanning-tree, prims-algorithm

I am trying to solve a problem on weight of MST and no of such MSTs.
[image: Graph]

In this probem, the weight of MST found by PRIM'S algorithm is 34, but there can be 2 MSTs possible; one tree with edge BC and the other with edge EF. But given answer is only 1.

Am i going wrong anywhere ?

Comment: I agree with you. There are two MST in this graph

Comment: The only tree I can find with EF edge has a value of 41 (CGEFBAD)

Comment: Consider the edges GC,GE,EF,FB,FA,AD constitute a tree of weight 34. I presume you have considered a path not a tree